# Does 'indecently' of 'indecently assaulting' weaken the meaning of assault?

Tags: vocabulary, legalese

> “A London jury has found him guilty of 12 counts of **indecently assaulting** four girls and young women.” ([Aussie ABC](http://www.abc.net.au/am/content/2014/s4036454.htm))

Does this modifier, *indecently*, weaken the meaning of *assaulting*? That is, does it mean he committed a sexually connected assault, but it was ***minor***? Or does the word, *indecently*, clarify or sub-categorize the meaning of assault? That is, does it mean the assaults were related to ***sexual*** assault?

Comment: I'm afraid this is General Reference. Sometimes plain *assault* is used to mean *indecent/sexual assault*, but it's usually explicitly specified. As to whether *sexual* assaults are considered more or less serious than "non-sexual" ones, that depends on both the specific incident, and the attitudes of the speaker to such matters.

Comment: I don't see why this question was closed. When I look up [indecently](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indecent) in the dictionary, I don't find any references to _indecent assault_. We need to be careful about voting to close questions where one or two "instinctive" mental connections need to be made between what a word or phrase means in context, and what is first found in the dictionary.

Comment: @J.R.: If you look up *common* in a dictionary I doubt you'll find anything explaining the difference between *common assault* and *indecent/sexual assault*. Off-hand I don't know whether one is more "serious" than the other, but the basic meaning of *indecent* must surely be general reference, and the seriousness of specific crimes is domain-specific, not directly relevant to ELL.

Comment: @Fumble - Just my opinion, but I don't think it's up to us to decide what is "relevant to ELL." If an English learner (a) reads a news story, (b) stumbles across a confusing term or phrase, (c) tries to figure out its meaning by consulting a dictionary, yet (d) still can't figure out what the word means, then they are **welcome** to ask here, so long as they provide sufficient context. In this case, the O.P. didn't ask for "the basic meaning of _indecent_," but for the meaning of _indecent_ in the context of the sentence provided.

Comment: @J.R.: But it *is* "up to us" to decide what's relevant. You more than me, since you're a mod, but collectively we as a community decide what is and isn't Off Topic. Since OP obviously knows he's reading about *indecent assault* in a ***legal*** context, I think it would be incumbent on him to google **define indecent assault** (which for all I know may be significantly different in Australia then the UK). Certainly the basic *improper, particularly in **sexual** contexts* meaning of *indecent* could be checked, to show it's nothing to do with ***minor** offences*.

Comment: @Fumble - Remember where you are! RE: _"Since OP obviously knows he's reading about indecent assault in a legal context"_ –  I wouldn't call that "obvious" for a learner – not from the information given. RE: _I think it would be incumbent on him to google_ `define indecent assault` – Not when the original reads "indecently assaulting;" I wouldn't expect all learners to know that "indecently assaulting" is a reference to "indecent assault," which is a legal term for a specific kind of assault. I think it's safe to assume this is NOT "obvious" to the O.P.; if it were, there would be no question.

Comment: @J.R.: Let's not split hairs. If you google **define indecently assaulting** I'm sure you'll get much the same results as from **define indecent assault**. I've just checked (in an "incognito" window, to avoid my personal search history skewing things), and the first page of results for each search are identical. And OP knows it's a legal context because the sentence starts with "A London jury has found him guilty".

Comment: @Fumble - Your queries rely on the O.P. knowing that the phrase should be parsed as `<indecent assault>` (or, as the case may be, `<indecently assaulting>`). Judging by the question, though, I assumed the phrase was parsed as `<indecently> <assaulting>`, thus causing the confusion. Each of your comments seems to indicate that it should be "obvious" those two words should be treated as a single syntactical unit. I don't assume all learners would know that or pick up on that.

Comment: @J.R.: The OP specifically refers to the word *indecently* as a "modifier", and since he asks whether this "weakens the meaning of *assaulting*" it's quite obvious he recognises the syntactic aspects of the usage. His *only* problem seems to be that he has erroneously assumed *assault* means ***sexual** assault* in the first place, and that therefore explicitly prefacing it by the word *indecently* might somehow imply it was a lesser kind of sexual assault. But as I've repeatedly said, he could easily have looked up (legal, not dictionary) definitions of various types of "assault".

Comment: @Fumble - I don't think "he could have easily looked up _legal_ definitions of various types of assault" is a very welcoming attitude for people who are not fluent English speakers. We are ELL, not a law school.

Comment: @J.R.: We really must call a halt on this one. I really don't think this particular user is going to feel "unwelcome" just because I take exception to one of his [671 questions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/504/listenever?tab=questions&sort=newest). In fact, I think I could reasonably expect him (her?) to be appreciative of the fact that for the past year and more I have assiduously addressed a great many of his questions (which in most cases I find to be both interesting *and* adequately researched/well-presented).

Comment: @Fumble - Fair enough, we've each had our say. :^) Let's shake hands and remain on good terms for our next "[healthy debate](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1100/this-site-isnt-english-morphosyntax-learners/1103#1103)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Indecent assault" is the formal name of the offense. It depends on the jurisdiction, but generally indecent assault is a sex crime that is a form of aggravated assault, which means it is more serious than simple assault. Many crimes were defined in the law decades or even centuries ago, which explains why crimes sometimes have archaic-sounding names like "indecent."

Comment: Are you saying [*Indecent Proposal*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107211/) is an "archaic" title for a movie? It's not exactly a historical drama.